# What is the series generated by the generating function : $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$?

Tags: proof-verification, generating-functions

I know that $$\frac{1}{(1-x)} = x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + \space ... \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$

When I differentiate $(1)$ with respect to $x$ I get the following function : 
$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2} = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + \space ...\space\space\space\space\space (2)$$

If I divide LHS and RHS of $(2)$ by $x$ I would get :

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{x} + 2 + 3x + 4x^2 + \space...$$

But from what I have seen from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneratingFunction.html) my derivation of the function $ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$ is completely wrong.

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The $x$ in the numerator on left side of (2) should not be there.

Comment: Actually you do not need differentiation: if $$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n $$ then $$\frac{f(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_n x^n$$ where $$A_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try redoing the derivative of $1/(1-x)$ more carefully.

Comment: I am terribly sorry for posting such a naive question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

A different approach, by a manual verification,

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n \geq 0}X^n,
$$

and so

$$
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x} =  \sum_{n \geq 0}X^n \cdot \sum_{m \geq 0}X^m = \sum_{i \geq 0}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^i1\right)X^i = \sum_{i \geq 0}(i+1)X^i
$$